# How to update UI time to time from IO thread using viewModelScope.launch in android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

doInBackground() takes a long time, say 1 hour's downloading, how to get the status say every 10 second?

```
fun execute() = viewModelScope.launch {
    onPreExecute() // UI thread
    val status= doInBackground() // IO thread. How to get the status every 10 second?
    onPostExecute(status) // UI thread
}
```

Comment: I'm too lazy to look into it myself, but because you want a stream of updates from a source that you don't know exactly how long it'll take, you may want to look into Flow here. Once a regular coroutine returns, it's not going to keep listening for the updates in `doInBackground()`. But a flow will listen for as long as your subscribed to the updates

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it just by launching another coroutine, which can be cancelled when the `doInBackground` call returns

```kotlin
fun execute() = viewModelScope.launch {
    onPreExecute()

    val progress = launch {
        while (isActive) {
            delay(PROGRESS_INTERVAL)
            // do something
            println("progress")
        }
    }

    val status = doInBackground()
    progress.cancel()

    println("$status")

    onPostExecute()
}
```